# When writing to a file, only the last line saves to my output file

Tags: c++

Im trying to write to a file but only the last line gets written to the file. I've tried opening and closing the file outside the loop but then nothing writes to the file

```
void getValues (double totalEnergy, double meanPowerConsumption, double maxPowerConsumption);

int main()
{
    double totalEnergy, meanPowerConsumption, maxPowerConsumption;
    getValues(totalEnergy, meanPowerConsumption, maxPowerConsumption);

    return 0;
}

void getValues(double totalEnergy, double meanPowerConsumption, double maxPowerConsumption)
{
    int x = 0;
    int c = 0;
    double p = 0;
    int i = 0;
    ifstream inFile;
    inFile.open("data.txt");

    if (inFile.fail())
    {   cerr << "Error opening file." << endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    // Declaring variables.
    double power1, power2, time1, time2, totalPower, timeConstant, changeInPower, totalTime, time, coloumns;
    double year, month, day, hour, minute, second, voltage, current, frequency;
    double accumulatedPower=0;

    while(!inFile.eof())
    {
        inFile >> year >> month >> day >> hour >> minute >> second >> voltage >> current >> frequency;

        //Should have taken into account 'Years','Months' and 'Days' but its throws the calculations into exponents.
        time2 = ((3600*hour) + (minute *60) + second);

        if (x==0)
        {
            timeConstant = 0;
            time1 = 0;
            totalTime = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            timeConstant = time2 - time1;
            totalTime = totalTime + timeConstant;
        }

        //cout << "time1: " << time1 << endl;
        //cout << "time2: " << time2 << endl;
        //cout << "Time Constant: " << timeConstant<< endl;
        //cout << "Total Time" << totalTime << endl;

        power2 = voltage*current;

        if (x==0)
        {
            power1 = 0;
            changeInPower = 0;
            totalPower = 0;
            totalEnergy = 0;
            meanPowerConsumption = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            changeInPower = (power1 + power2)/2;
            totalPower = totalPower + changeInPower;
        }

        // cout << "Counter" << c << endl;
        // Assumed that mean powerconsumption is the average of all powers entered.
        meanPowerConsumption = totalPower / c;

        // Testing Variables.
        //cout << "power1: " << power1 << endl;
        //cout << "power2: " << power2 << endl;
        //cout << "Change in Power: " << changeInPower << endl;
        //cout << "total Power: " << totalPower << endl;


        //Numerical Integration:
        totalEnergy = totalEnergy + (timeConstant*changeInPower);

        //Counter Loop:

        if (power2 > maxPowerConsumption)
        {
            maxPowerConsumption = power2;
        }


        accumulatedPower = accumulatedPower + power1;
        time = time2 - time1;
        p = p + time;


        ofstream outFile;
        outFile.open("byhour.txt");

        for (coloumns=0; p>=3599; coloumns++)
        {
            i++;
            outFile << i << " " << accumulatedPower/3600000 << endl;

            accumulatedPower=0;
            p=0;
        }

        outFile.close();

        cout << "coloumns: " << i  << endl;
        cout << "P value " << p << endl;
        cout << "accumulated power" << accumulatedPower << endl;

        cout << "The total Energy is: " << totalEnergy/3600000 << "KwH" << endl;
        cout << "The mean power consumption is: " << meanPowerConsumption << endl;
        cout << "The Max Power Consumption is:" << maxPowerConsumption << endl;
        cout << endl ;

        c++;
        x++;

        time1 = time2;
        power1 = power2;
    }

    ofstream outStats;
    outStats.open("stats.txt");

    outStats << totalEnergy/3600000 << endl;
    outStats << meanPowerConsumption << endl;
    outStats << maxPowerConsumption << endl;

    outStats.close();
}
```

That's the full code. I tried taking it out and putting it back in (open and close file). Nothing has worked so far

Comment: Try to pick a few tags that are remotely correct.

Comment: The `for` loop makes very little sense. It will run - at most - once (if `p >= 3599` at the start). The `p = 0` line at the end ensures it will never run more than once.

Comment: It will run again because I set p back to zero. The code is fine, I've done tons of variable tests. Its just not writing all the lines to the file

Answer (score 6):

You are opening and closing the file in a loop; based on the default mode it's opening to the first position in the file, so each write you are opening the file, writing to the start of the file (likely overwriting what was there before), and closing it.

You should open the file once, write out in a loop, and close outside the loop.

Comment: I've tried doing that but then nothing writes to the file?

Comment: Then you're doing something else wrong.  Post what you are trying with the open/close outside the loop.

Comment: @user3504476 Then probably something else was wrong you don't show here.

Answer (score 0):

Your `for` loop is actually running (at most) once.

```
for (coloumns=0; p>=3599; coloumns++)
{
    ...
    p=0;
}
```

Assuming `p` is at least 3599 at the start of the loop, the loop will run only a single time, because `p` gets set to 0 at the end of the loop (meaning the test will be false the next time around and the loop stops).

If `p` is less than 3599 at the start, of course, it won't run at all.

Comment: No the loop runs continuously because p = p + timeConstant. Therefore the value of p will increase up until 3599

Comment: But that's not inside the `for` loop.

Comment: Yeah I only want my loop to run once, then set p back to zero and then run the loop again when p gets to 3599. Therefore the loop should have run at least 13 times before the input file runs out of lines.

Comment: If it's only supposed to run once, it doesn't make sense to use a `for` loop. Maybe `if (p>=3599) { ... }` is what you want?

Comment: I just tried that. Its still not working :( Any other suggestions?